# can you help me with version and buy sell signal for pine editor? Can you help me update this to work with version 5 and "buy sell signal?

Tags: editor, pine-script-v5, indicator

Can you help me update this to work with version 5 and "buy sell signal? There is no pine editor version. I am trying to make version 5. I also want to add buy and sell signal. even better if i can hide the values of 80 and 20.

```
study(title = "instagram: askincantum", shorttitle = "instagram: askincantum", overlay = true)

//Mode
RSI = input(title="Line", defval=80, minval=1, maxval = 100)

//RSI
src = close,

ep = 2 * RSI - 1
auc = ema( max( src - src[1], 0 ), ep )
adc = ema( max( src[1] - src, 0 ), ep )
x1 = (RSI - 1) * ( adc * 70 / (100-70) - auc)
ub = iff( x1 >= 0, src + x1, src + x1 * (100-70)/70 )
x2 = (RSI - 1) * ( adc * 30 / (100-30) - auc)
lb = iff( x2 >= 0, src + x2, src + x2 * (100-30)/30 )

//Affichage
plot(avg(ub, lb), color=blue , style = line, linewidth=2, title="Line")


len = input(20, minval=1, title="Entry")
src1 = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input(title="Offset", type=integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = wma(src1, len)
plot(out, title="Entry", color=yellow, linewidth = 2, offset=offset)


plotshape(crossover(RSI, len) , style = shape.triangleup , location = location.belowbar , color = green , size = size.large)
plotshape(crossunder(RSI, len) , style = shape.triangledown , location = location.abovebar , color = red , size = size.large)
```

Answer (score 0):

**My recommendation, add //@version=4 at the very top**
You'll need to do the above to see the option to convert your script to V5.

Then, from PineEditor, you'll see an option to convert to Version 5, then click Save
You'll probably see some syntax issues to fix from the error console to be fixed - you'll see understandable error messages

Documentation: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html

Comment: I'm trying to make version 1-2-3-4 but I'm getting an error can you help me?